# How to read in numbers from n lines into a Scala list?

Tags: list, scala

This is for an online judge. I am trying to learn some Scala in the process.

The input format looks like

```
4
543534
6756
4564
363773
```

So the first line is n, and then the next n lines contain elements that need to go into a list.

Right now I read n by using `readInt()` but I don't know how to then say "now read the next n lines and place everything into a list".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
val n = io.StdIn.readInt
val list = ( 0 to n ).map( (x) -> io.StdIn.readLine ).toList
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line if you trust the input and ignore that first range value.

```
val list = io.StdIn.getLines.drop(1).map(_.toInt).toList
```